# how to setting time in jquery?

Tags: jquery, time, settings

i'm newbie at web developing.
i have some input form.i'm using `jquery 1.4.2`
inside that i have one textfield specially for input time.
i want every one no need to type manually.
and also make easy for every user.
can you tell me how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're after a better UI way to go about this.  There are many more date than time widgets out there, but there are time pickers available, my personal favorite is this here: [jQuery.timepicker](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/), give it a look.

It's jquery UI Themeable, and if you need a more specific time you can still type in the box, so it works both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Say in your HTML you have:

```
<input id='intime' type='text' name='intime'>
```

Then you can set it with:

```
$('#intime').val(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date Object.  See "15.9.2 The Date Constructor Called as a Function" in the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) for more info.